# How to install clangd on Mac?

Tags: macos, emacs, clang, spacemacs, emacs-lsp

I am trying to use `clangd` with Spacemacs according to the [c-cpp](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/develop/layers/%2Blang/c-c%2B%2B#clangd) page. I have tried downloading the macOS binary for LLVM and I have followed [this](https://github.com/onivim/oni/issues/826#issuecomment-340307708) and [this](https://github.com/thomasjo/atom-ide-cpp/issues/20#issue-467335468), but when I run `which clangd`, it says it cannot be found. I have also run `brew install llvm`, but that also doesn't show that `clangd` is in my path. I do have a binary under `/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/9.0.0_1/bin`, but my LSP doesn't do anything when I restart Emacs and open a C++ source file. I have `/usr/local/bin` in my path.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I added `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/` to my PATH and that worked. Thanks to [Mikael Springer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6149135/mikael-springer). I wonder why it wasn't working with the other location (and why I have multiple copies of llvm binaries).

Answer (score 1):

I have the following in my init.el with Emacs, not Spacemacs;

```
(use-package lsp-clients
    :config
    (setq lsp-clients-clangd-executable "/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clangd")
    (setq lsp-clients-clangd-args '("-j=4" "-background-index" "-log=info" "-pretty" "-resource-dir=/Applications/Xcode9.2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0")))
```

As you can see I use `use-package` for Emacs package management but the important part is setting the lsp-clients-clangd-* variables. I install LLVM (and clangd) using `brew install llvm`.
I don't know how or if this might help you since you use Spacemacs and I am not familiar with configuring Spacemacs.

Comment: I added `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/` to my PATH and that worked. Thanks! I wonder why it wasn't working with the other location (and why I have multiple copies of llvm binaries).