# How to install clangd on Mac (preferably with Homebrew)

Tags: macos, homebrew, clangd

I have used `brew install llvm`, so older answers (and [the clangd website](https://clangd.llvm.org/installation.html)) say that clangd should already be installed.

But in the current version this seems to not be the case. *clangd* is not in my path and none of the folders I looked into have that binary.

I found these answers (none of them work):

- Put `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/` in your path.
  I assume installing llvm should have created that directory, but it does not exist.
  ([Link to Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59185976/how-to-install-clangd-on-mac))
- Find clangd in other folders (run `find /usr/local/ -name 'clangd'`). This doesn't have any results ([Link to superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/1449404/how-to-install-clangd-not-clang-on-mac-os))
- Use the `--with-toolchain` flag for Homebrew while installing llvm.

  > Error: invalid option: --with-toolchain

  ([Link to apple Stack Exchange question dealing with clang++](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/227026/how-to-install-recent-clang-with-homebrew))
- Use the `--with-clang` flag for Homebrew while installing llvm

  > Error: invalid option: --with-clang

  ([Same link as the --with-toolchain idea](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/227026/how-to-install-recent-clang-with-homebrew))

So my questions are:

1. As of August 2021, how do I install clangd on a MacBook?
2. Do I really have to manually build everything from sources?

---

Further information:

- This is a [MacBook (M1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Air_(Apple_silicon)#Third_generation_(Retina_with_Apple_silicon))
- I found a *clangd* executable at `/opt//homebrew/Cellar/llvm/12.0.1/bin/clangd`
- Running `brew info llvm` results in a message containing

  > If you need to have llvm first in your PATH, run: 
  > echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

In that folder I found a *clangd* executable too, so I guess I should add this to my path instead of `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems the questioner is using an M1 Mac. `/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin` should be the directory to be added into `PATH`, but not the `/usr/local` one.

---

`llvm` is keg-only, which means it was not [symbolic linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) into `/usr/local` (`/opt/homebrew` for M1 Mac). `llvm` bring its own libraries. To avoid these libraries shadowing the system one, Homebrew choose *not* to link the package, which results in binaries not linked into `/usr/local/bin`.

`clangd` is in `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin`, you need to add this directory into `PATH`. Save the following content into your shell init files ([.zshrc](https://wiki.debian.org/Zsh#Configuration) for [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) (`zsh`), and [.bash_profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example) for Bash)

```bash
# For x86 Mac
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"

# For M1 Mac
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"
```

Then start a new shell, and type `clangd --version` to have a test.

Check `brew info llvm` for more information.

Comment: As I said, `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin` does not exists after `brew install llvm`. And no other location inside `/usr/local` contains a `clangd` binary.

Comment: @Proof-By-Sledgehammer Are you using a M1 Mac? What's the output of `brew info llvm`, can you paste it in the question?

Comment: It looks like `brew info llvm` actually contains the information needed to get clangd to work. I am not sure if it is good practice to add the given directory to my path (although `brew info` tells me to do it). Maybe you can update your answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I will try to remember to upvote your answer once I have enough reputation